How To Get 220v In One Wire?
I have a Chinese device that calls for a hard wired 220VAC single-phase connection that will pull 25amps. The connection required is 3 wires only. L (Live), N (Neutral) and PV (Ground).
How can I get 220v into a single wire? Previously, I've always seen L1 and L2 on devices that require 240v single phase. The manufacturer said it will operate between 200-250v, but it was designed for 220v.
I'm wiring the device up in a building that has 3 phase power.
My guess is use a dual pole 25amp breaker then wire that to a transformer that has input for two hots and can output one hot wire. Does that sound like a good way to go about it and if so, where do you get such a transformer?
I've also read that you could wire the Neutral as L2 but that was for a mini-split someone else was installing. I remember an electrician friend said to me a while ago that the Neutral is required if it's powering a screen on the device, which it is in this instance.

A Chinese device requiring 220/240v at 25 amps might not be a good idea to use, no matter how much you saved buying it.  Does the device at least have an UL/ELT label to say it is safe to use?  A building with three phase power is probably not a single family house where a non electrician might be allowed to connect the device, so you probably need a licensed electrician for the connection to be done according to local regulations.

Depending what the device is and if it requires neutral(unlikely), then quite possible to use one hot/live to L1 and a second hot to N.  Most simple 240v only devices like heaters work this way.  Some 240v devices like dryers/stoves use 240v and 120v and need two hots and neutral.

Re: "a building that has 3 phase power" -- what is the nominal voltage of the 3 phase power? If you're in the US, it's 208/120, and the 208 is in the range specified; no need for a transformer. Whether that is safe with a device expecting a "neutral" is a separate matter.

What is the device and what is the building? 3-phase is awfully rare in Home Improvement contexts.

Where in the world is this? The building has 3-phase, but do the individual inits have 3-phase or do they only have two of the phases? Is there a neutral as well?

connect L2 to N,  yes, that works and is safe except when it doesn't work or is not safe.

Ignoring (cough cough) safety for a moment, any device that is designed for:

L (Live)
N (Neutral)
PV (Ground)

should work fine with any "named" wires as long as the voltage between them is within the desired range. Which means that a device designed for a 200V - 250V range (which is actually quite common - it allows for use nearly anywhere in the world) will run just fine in some places using:

Hot
Neutral

and in other places (e.g., US/Canada) using:

Hot 1
Hot 2

and in that situation not connecting neutral at all.
The key is that provided there are no safety issues (more below about that), an appliance really doesn't know or care whether one of the wires is neutral or not. Due to the nature of alternating current, you can even connect Neutral/Hot instead of Hot/Neutral (as I have found too many places in my house...) and everything will work just fine. Until it doesn't.
Which brings us to SAFETY.
In many places, particularly in the US/Canada, neutral is bonded to ground. That has a number of implications, one of which is that if neutral touches any exposed metal then it is nominally safe for a person to touch that same exposed metal, because there is no difference (voltage) between neutral (that metal part) and ground (where the person is standing in bare and wet feet).
A specific common example is an Edison light socket. The outer ring - which is easy to touch accidentally when changing a light bulb - is connected to neutral (provided the wiring is all done properly) and the inner "button" - which is much harder to accidentally touch - is connected to hot. That makes it relatively hard for someone to get shocked when changing a light bulb - they would have to (a) touch the hard to reach part and (b) also be vulnerable to a shock due to wet hands or other factors. Best practice is to turn off the light switch (and that switch should itself turn off hot, not neutral - unlike some of the ones I had to fix in my house...) because that takes hot totally away, making it 100% safe. But even without turning off the light switch, neutral and hot in the right locations makes it pretty safe.
Which means that the safety of installing this device on Hot/Hot instead of Hot/Neutral depends on the design of the device. Does it have a metal case or other exposed metal parts? Is it something that is subject to damage that could cause problems with the wiring? Is it something subject to a lot of vibration that could make wires get loose over time? Is it within easy reach or is it mounted high up and safely away from hands?
Depending on the answers to those questions, you can make the decision as to whether or not to install this device. In the US/Canada and many other countries it is against the electrical code, and by extension against the law, to install equipment that is not properly certified for use in that jurisdiction, typically noted by certification/listing from UL, ETL, TUV or a similar testing laboratory. That doesn't mean an unlisted item is unsafe, but it is a factor to consider.

Great answer. I'd add a few niggling details. In US/Canada the neutral supply conductors are bonded to ground. The appliance conductor called neutral should not be bonded to the appliance ground conductor within the appliance at any point. (Generators have some special cases, which I'll ignore here). And a fairly common instance of such a hot/hot/ground 240V connection are EVSE.

you seem to be asking questions.
